# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a problem in configuring a pipeline in jenkins that must use a maven functionnality to build and do continues integration, and since I am new to goovy I came to you for help, I have put this code as a goovy script to my pipeline:
`

```
node{
  stage ('Build') {

    svn 'http://192.168.197.143/svn/testrepo4'

    withMaven(jdk: 'jdk2', maven: 'C:\\apache-maven-3.6.0-bin\\apache-maven-3.6.0', mavenSettingsConfig: '882a5bcf-ee82-49a9-8a32-4ffe1fe7d81a', mavenSettingsFilePath: 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.m2\\settings.xml', tempBinDir: '') {
} {

      // Run the maven build
      bat "mvn clean install"

    } // withMaven will discover the generated Maven artifacts, JUnit Surefire & FailSafe & FindBugs reports...
  }
}
```

`

as you can guess I am using a windows server 2016 host and my svn repository address is 192.168.197.143 so that line is correct, I have this output while checking for a build->

```
console output
"Started by timer
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\pipeline test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] svn
Updating http://192.168.197.143/svn/testrepo4 at revision '2019-02-21T10:15:23.667 +0100'
At revision 2

No changes for http://192.168.197.143/svn/testrepo4 since the previous build
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [{jdk=jdk2, maven=C:\apache-maven-3.6.0-bin\apache-maven-3.6.0, mavenSettingsConfig=882a5bcf-ee82-49a9-8a32-4ffe1fe7d81a, mavenSettingsFilePath=C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\settings.xml, tempBinDir=}, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@c22fb7]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:566)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:504)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:217)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:176)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor411.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:6)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor410.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:121)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:182)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

"
(I know that the problem begins with the error but I have copied/pasted all the output for you if you require further information)
thanks for the help in advance

Comment: I used the pipeline syntax code generator by the way

Comment: can you please try withMaven(jdk: 'java-1.8') and delete all the other arguments ?

Comment: I will try but the problemis that some variables are not set

Comment: the same problem still persists

Comment: I think your `maven: ` argument inside withMaven(...) is not correct. You need to provide the Maven installation configured on the Global Tool Configuration page in Jenkins. ie. some id not the actual path. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin#PipelineMavenPlugin-Usage

Comment: And, from where does `tempBinDir` names comes? I can't seem to find it in the docs.

Comment: it was generated from the pipeline syntax generator